# Uploading MDB into postgis with non geometry tables in the mdb

Tags: postgis, osgeo4w

In osgeo4w I am uploading an mdb into postgis. It works perfectly with all the geometry content within the personal geodatabase, but it does not take the tables from the personal geodatabase.

Is there any way of adding some functionality to the following osgeo4w command in order to also extract the non geometry tables from the personal geodatabase?

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=... dbname=... user=... password=..." filename.mdb
```

UPDATE

When using ogrinfo it does not recognize tables without a geometry. They are in the .mdb when you open it in Arcmap.

```
ogrinfo filename.mdb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access non-spatial .mdb tables through the [ODBC driver](http://gdal.org/drv_odbc.html).

In my experience, it is tricky depending on 32-bit, 64-bit, additional Windows installs and configuring ODBC data sources.  I'm not sure if this will work with OSGeo4W, you may need the appropriate binaries from [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/).  You can see additional information that hints at some of this [on the GDAL list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-MDB-tools-td4664425.html#a5227670) and this [ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5594).  Unfortunately, I don't know more specific information that would help you and that would be highly specific to the architecture of your machine and installs anyway, for myself I've both succeeded and failed at this.

Answer (score 0):

Zuenie,

If you have PostgreSQL installed on windows, check out the recently released PostGIS 2.2.0 windows bundle available on stackbuilder and http://postgis.net/windows_downloads  .

It comes packed with ogrfdw foreign data wrapper (which uses GDAL 2.0.1 shipped with PostGIS 2.2). We bundled ODBC support in it because we needed it for accessing non-spatial MS access dbs.

Here is an article describing how to use it:

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/346-Querying-MS-Access-and-other-ODBC-data-sources-with-OGR_FDW.html

Like I said, If you have PostGIS 2.2 both 32bit/64bit (PostgreSQL 9.3+) you can use it.